# How to efficiently list prime with a very specific property

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

I noticed that my phone number `06 xx xx xx xx` is a prime number. Ok that cool ... But if you had the country code (+33 for france), `33 6 xx xx xx xx` is still prime ! And that is awesome !

I am wondering, how rare are such numbers ?

- What would be the best way to compute euler's totient function for so large numbers ?
- How can I efficiently list all those numbers ?

Comment: Computing Euler's totient for a prime is fairly easy ...

Comment: I guess you should apply [Prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "probability" that a nine-digit number is prime is approximately $\frac1{\ln(10^9)}\approx 0.048$. The probability that prepending $33$ produces a prime again is approximately $\frac1{\ln(33\cdot 10^9)}\approx 0.041$. Then again, it is already clear that the second number is odd (and not a multiple of $3$ or $11$), so *given* that the national French number is prime, the probability for the international number should be multiplied with $\frac 21\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac{11}{10}$. Hence the overall probability is (quite heuristically!)$$ \approx\frac{33}{11}\cdot 0.041\cdot0.048\approx 0.0066$$
which suggests that you may share your luck with one in about 150 of your fellow countrypersons (having a phone). The exact numbers may differ from country to country. For example in Germany (country code `+49`) the internatinal number might suddenly be a multiple of $3$.

The first such numbers are 
$$+33600000001, +33600000019, +33600000127,, +33600000139, +33600000283, +33600000299, +3360000347, +33600000407, +33600000571, +33600000607, +33600000617, +33600000671, +33600000689, +33600000809, +33600000883, +33600000949, +33600000997$$
which suggests that the result above was overly pessimistic.